# Error in Flutter when trying to create a form

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Gather'),),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () { },
              child: Text('Start Matching!'),
              )
          ],),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Everything seems to be fine with the code itself except the end. At the end there is one red squiggly line under the ; and it will stop my whole code from running.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the code pasted above is incorrect.
`);` ends the `return Scaffold(`, so you're missing 2 `}}`.

Also, you may need to wrap your scaffold, e.g. `MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(...))`.